# how to pass arrays and return array values of 2-d matrices?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, arguments

call from main

```
matrix_multiplication(arrayA,arrayB,row1,col1,col2);
```

function definition

```
float matrix__multiplication(float **arrayA,float **arrayB,int row1,int col1,int col2)
{
float result[row1][col2];
result[][]=....

return result;
}
```

I wanted to know how to pass 2d arrays in function call,
how to receive in function definition
and how to return the result matrix?

Comment: There is huge difference between `type arr[][]` and `type** arr`. Choose one. Also, note that your `result` is a stack variable and won't exist anymore after you exit the function!

Comment: Perhaps using a std::vector would make your life easier http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using raw pointers for your arrays like this is more C style than C++.  Use vector of vector (indexing is still very efficient).

```
size_t rows(5);
size_t columns(15);
vector<float> row(columns);
vector<vector<float>> matrix(rows, row);
matrix[0][0] = 0.1f;
```

Better yet wrap the underlying storage in a Matrix class that implements the required matrix operations, holds and enforces dimensions, ensures matrices are compatible for the multiplication, and so on.

```
class Matrix
{ 
public:
  Matrix(const int _rows, const int _cols) : rows(_rows), cols(_cols)
  {
  }

  Matrix Multiply(const Matrix& rhs);

private:
  vector<vector<float>> storage;
  size_t rows;
  size_t cols;
};

Matrix Matrix::multiply(const Matrix& rhs)
{
  Matrix result(*this, rhs);   // construct matrix of right dimensions
  // multiply the operands
  return result;     // modern compilers do not copy construct the result
}
```

If your matrix demands are complex you could consider a library like [Boost.UBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) versus roll your own.  This is templated code and supports specializations for sparse, diagonal and other common types of matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I would it something like this by passing a reference to the 2D array (in fact an D1 X D2) array of any type. This would also avoid any need to return back anything.

If the function need to modify the input array argument, remove the const.

```
void f( T const (&r)[D1][D2] ){}

int main() { 
   float fbuf[10][3];
   f(fbuf);
}
```

If you however insist on having the function return a 2D array, you may do something like so:

```
template<class T, size_t D1, size_t D2>
T (&f( T const (&r)[D1][D2] ))[D1][D2]{
   T temp[D1][D2];
   return temp;
}

int main() { 
   float fbuf[10][3];
   f(fbuf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have wrote is not a valid c++ code. In order to initialize `result` to proper size, `row` and `col` need to be compile time constants which they are not. You either return a `float**` from your function which you allocate locally, or (better) you pass a pre-allocated `float** result` as another parameter to you function (which you still can return). However, usually you would not use 2-d arrays to store matrices, you'd rather define a linear storage for a matrix in a 1-d array and define appropriate accessors.

```
float** matrix__multiplication(float **arrayA,float **arrayB,float **result, int row1,int col1,int col2)  
{  
 // ...
 return result;  
}

// caller needs to allocate (and de-allocate) space (see the mess?):
result = new float* [row1];
std::for_each(result, result + row1, [col2] (float*& pCurr) -> void {
 pCurr = new float[col2];
});  

result = matrix_multiplication(a, b, result, row1, col1, col2);
```